# iTextSharp: fields generated in a table not shown in adobe reader

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, adobe-reader

I'm trying to generate a pdf and fill in some fields at the same time. I do this two ways. The first by creating a text field and setting the text.

```
var _text = new TextField(writer,
                new Rectangle(sectionX + textLength + 2, fieldIncrementer - 3,
                    sectionX + Convert.ToSingle(xElement.Parent.Attribute("width").Value),
                    fieldIncrementer + fieldFontSize - 2), xElement.Attribute("name").Value.Trim());
if (xElement.Attribute("autoFill") != null)
 {
   _text.Text = FormAutoFill.Instance.GetValue(xElement.Attribute("autoFill").Value);
 }
```

This works well. The other way is for creating a text field that sits on top of a cell in a table.

```
//Create the text field that will be attached to the cell
var tf = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(67, 585, 140, 800),
                tableDescendant.Attribute("name").Value); //The rectangle will be ignored by the cell event
tf.Alignment = alignment;
tf.Font = FONT;
if (tableDescendant.Attribute("autoFill") != null)
 {
   tf.Text = tableDescendant.Attribute("autoFill").Value;
 }
//Create an empty phrase since the cell won't take an empty string
var phrase = new Phrase(" ",
     new Font(FONT, FontSize, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK));
//Create the empty cell
var tbCell = new PdfPCell(phrase);
var events = new FieldPositioningEvents(writer, tf.GetTextField());
events.AddField("djdjdj", tf.GetTextField());
tbCell.CellEvent = events;
```

This method works great when viewing the pdf through BlueBeam Revu, but in Adobe Reader, the fields that are in a table are not visible.[image: Can't see in adobe]
Even stranger, if I click the button on the top of reader that says "Highlight Existing Fields" I see the text that supposed to be there, but it's squashed!
[image: Squashed!]

I hope someone can help me out here, I see no difference between the first method and the second method.

UPDATE #1: It appears that the same behavior is exhibited in bluebeam after I print. That is, the text is squashed.

Comment: Please share a sample PDF.

Comment: @mkl I wasn't sure what was the best way to share it, so I put it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/l7iwwvryngcytjf/example.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I looked at your sample file, and was surprised about the dimensions of the field's appearance's  bounding box:

```
/BBox   [0, 0, 73, 215]
```

It has the width and height of your original `TextField`, the values which as per your comment will be ignored by the cell event.

```
var tf = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(67, 585, 140, 800),
            tableDescendant.Attribute("name").Value); //The rectangle will be ignored by the cell event
```

Indeed, the cell event does not use those values, but before the cell event is triggered, you set th value of the field:

```
tf.Text = tableDescendant.Attribute("autoFill").Value;
```

Here an appearance is generated for that field value, and that appearance uses those initial field dimensions you hoped to be ignored.

To solve this, you should try setting the value after the cell event is triggered, i.e. after the table is layout'ed.

Alternatively you can switch off the generation of appearances altogether, e.g. as proposed by coderRed by creating a pdf stamper as follows:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(xmlFormDoc + ".pdf"); 
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,new FileStream("tempdoc.pdf",FileMode.Create));
stamper.AcroFields.GenerateAppearances = false; 
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();        
File.Replace("tempdoc.pdf",xmlFormDoc+".pdf",null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Due to the way I've implemented the object, it's not very easy to change the text after adding the table to the document. How would I go about switching the generation of the appearances? Do you mean setting the .Text after tying in the event to the cell?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by creating a stamper after I had created my pdf file. I tried to find a way to set generateappearance in the writer but was unsuccessful.

Comment: *How would I go about switching the generation of the appearances?* I'll look that up. *Do you mean setting the .Text after tying in the event to the cell?* no, after layout'ing the cell, I.e. drawing the table in question.

Comment: It appears that this same approach may have caused some issues when I want to flatten the form. I would appreciate it if you could check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394687/itextsharp-flattening-a-field-in-table-cell-shifts-text-upward